# Issues creating a new JSON object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

Sorry I am new to programming, could anyone help with this please. I can log the profile object, a JSON object with 10 items, but I cant log the vehQ, which should contain only 3. Have I written this incorrectly?

```
        let profile = await this.getProfileDetails(params)
        console.log(profile)
            var vehQ = {}
            if (profile ) {

                vehQ["profileID"] = profile[0].profileID
                vehQ["regNumber"] = profile[0].regNumber
                vehQ["compatibility"] = profile[0].compatibility
                console.log(vehQ)
```

Comment: What output do you get when you do `console.log(vehQ)`?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(vehQ))

Answer (score 0):

You're probably receiving the JSON as string, you need to parse it to JS object.

```js
const parsedProfile = JSON.parse(profile);
```